# Joining the closest prior timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of user's website interactions:

```
::: site_interactions :::
+-------+---------------------+
| user  | timestamp           |
+-------+---------------------+
| john  | 2017-01-01 15:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
| john  | 2017-01-01 15:30:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
| sarah | 2017-01-03 12:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

And a secondary table of in-store transactions:

```
::: store_transactions :::
+-------+---------------------+
| user  | timestamp           |
+-------+---------------------+
| john  | 2017-01-02 08:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
| sarah | 2017-01-02 09:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
| tim   | 2017-01-02 10:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

I want to join the website interactions onto the in-store stuff, but returning only:

a) the most recent interaction timestamp, but also

b) the interaction timestamp needs to be before the transaction timestamp

So in this example, I'd end up with:

```
+-------+---------------------+------------------------+
| user  | timestamp           | last_prior_interaction |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------+
| john  | 2017-01-02 08:00:00 | 2017-01-01 15:30:00    |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------+
| sarah | 2017-01-02 09:00:00 | NULL                   |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------+
| tim   | 2017-01-02 10:00:00 | NULL                   |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

I suspect the answer is in using HAVING and MIN, but I just can't wrap my head around how that works when I also need to enforce that prior interaction predicate. Any tips?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I have the data in both MySQL and BigQuery but I guess I'll stick to MySQL :)

Comment: Any luck with your issue?

Comment: @penitent_tangent . . . If the data is in multiple databases, then you should make that clear in the question.  Some people have a habit of adding database tags to "expand the audience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the latest timestamp before the transaction even if a new interaction has occured after, here is a working code:

```
SELECT T.user, I.timestamp
FROM store_transactions T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT I.user, MAX(I.timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM site_interactions I 
    INNER JOIN store_transactions T ON I.user = T.user
    WHERE I.timestamp < T.timestamp
    GROUP BY I.user
) I ON I.user = T.user
```

Comment: This works! Thanks Gregory. Working demo for future users: http://rextester.com/KDCE6826

Answer (score 1):

http://rextester.com/WILC99478

```
SELECT
  st.username
, st.timestamp
, CASE WHEN si.timestamp < st.timestamp THEN si.timestamp ELSE NULL END 'last_prior_interaction'
FROM store_transactions st
LEFT JOIN (SELECT username
                , MAX(timestamp) timestamp
             FROM site_interactions                    
         GROUP BY username) si
               ON si.username = st.username
```

rextester did not like the field name "user", so I replaced it with "username".

Full disclosure: I feel like the "si.timestamp < st.timestamp" part can be handled in the JOIN itself, but this will pull the data that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jake - this is close, but if a user has site interactions before and after the offline transaction, it will return null. See e.g; http://rextester.com/EZC19671

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
Select st.user, st.timestamp, ut.timestamp  from   
    Store_transaction st left join site_transaction ut 
    on ut.user=st.user and ut.timestamp > st.timestamp;
```

Comment: I see how this would return only prior timestamps, but how does this ensure that it's the most recent one?